# Pip version change

Tags: python, pip

I have python 2.7 and 3.5 installed on my Ubuntu. There are also corresponding pip installed. Just `pip` refers to the pip of python 3.5 , or in other words `pip=pip3`. I want `pip` to refer to `pip2`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to ensure this is to adjust your `PATH` so the directory with `pip2` in it comes before the one with `pip3` in it.

Another alternative is to run the `pip2` command instead of `pip`.

Nowadays, however, it's safest to use the command `python -m pip` rather than just `pip`. As long as you know which `python` you are running this guarantees it uses the right version of `pip`.

So you might consider `python2 -m pip` and `python3 -m pip` to keep the environments separate from each other.